# How did Louis Tully know Slimer?

Tags: ghostbusters

In *Ghostbusters 2*, Louis Tully puts on a proton pack and heads to a bus stop in the hope of helping the real Ghostbusters at the museum.  The bus comes, and Louis sees that Slimer is driving:

[image]

He clearly recognizes the ghost:

> Louis Tully: [waits at the bus stop only to find Slimer is driving the bus] **Oh, it's you.**
>
> Louis Tully: [Slimer offers Louis to come aboard the bus] Okay, but I didn't know you had your license.

I don't recall Louis ever meeting Slimer in either movie.  He wasn't there when Slimer was first captured, Slimer wasn't visible when the storage unit was shut down, and we don't see Slimer again after that, except for a brief scene in which he is devouring an entire push-cart full of hot dogs (Louis was already possessed at that point, and didn't see Slimer eating the hot dogs).

So how did Louis know who/what Slimer was?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According the [Ed Naha novelisation](http://ghostbusters.wikia.com/wiki/Ghostbusters_II:_Novel) of the film, the Ghostbusters have allowed Louis substantial access to their operation. He knows what Slimer looks like, that he's one of the earliest ghosts captured and some info about his habits of gluttony and mischief. At best guess, it seems likely that they've either provided a vivid verbal description or, more likely, allowed him to view various ghosts and ghouls that exist within their containment system:

You may also wish to note that in both novelisations, there's what appears to be a deleted scene set between the scene with Dana's bathtub and the scene with Dana and Venkman going out for dinner in which Louis attempts to catch Slimer after it escapes from the containment system:

> Louis recognized the creature as one of the first trapped by the
>   Ghostbusters years earlier ... the Slimer.
>
> Slimer, unaware of Louis's presence, glanced down-ward as Louis
>   glanced upward.
>
> Both Slimer and Louis let out bloodcurdling yells and ran in opposite
>   directions. Slimer was the better for it. He disappeared through a
>   wall. Louis collided with the firehouse's brick wall and knocked
>   himself more senseless than usual. "Help!" he screamed to no one in
>   particular. "There's a thing"
>
> Louis ran out of the room, knowing full well that Slimer would be back
>   for more food and that Louis had just lost at least three perfecdy
>   good Twinkies to an apparition.

and

> The green ghost Slimer poked his head down through the ceiling and
>   scanned the room for the grub. "Okay, let's boogie," Louis whispered.
>
> Louis whirled around and fired a proton stream at Slimer just as
>   Janine entered the room. Slimer retreated easily. Janine gulped and
>   ducked as a ragged bolt of energy streaked across the lab and seared
>   the wall behind her.
>
> Louis stood there, trembling. "Ohmigod!" he shouted. "I'm sorry. I
>   didn't mean to do that. It was an accident."
>
> He flip-flopped across the lab to Janine. The recep-tionist slowly
>   straightened up. "What are you doing up here?" she asked him.
>
> Louis began to sweat. "I was trying to get that smelly green ghost.
>   The guys asked me to help out. I'm like the fifth Ghostbuster."

Stills from this scene can been seen in the [Ghostbusters II: Storybook](http://www.gbfans.com/ghostbusters-2/books/storybook-jovial-bob-stein/)

[image]

and described in more detail (along with another still photo) in the [Ghostbusters II: Junior Novel](http://ghostbusters.wikia.com/wiki/Ghostbusters_II:_Junior_Novel):

[image]

Comment: I don't remember the earlier scene you mentioned.  Is it in the movie, or just the script and/or novelization?

Comment: @WadCheber - Good question. Checking now

Comment: I've seen the movie at least 5-10 times, and I don't remember Louis going after Slimer at all.  I might be having a brain fart, but I would hope that some memory of the scene would still be in my head if I had seen it before.

Comment: Whew.  Glad to know my brain isn't broken.

Answer (score 2):

He saw him in the first half of Ghostbusters 2. That scene was between the court and the toaster scenes.

[image: the scene]